# Any quick way to convert std::vector to CComSafeArray

Tags: c++, stdvector, safearray

Is there any quick way to convert std::vector to CComSafeArray. I'm currently write a piece of code which basically converting 5 or 6 vector to CComSafeArray (not in a iteration). In which, big block of code(release old space, create new safearray, copy) emerge. I really hope I can convert it easily.

As we can write a method to do this conversion, I'm actually looking for useful function lying in a corner of libraries etc. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Well you could just ask Stack Overflow. That's quick.

Comment: Is there a type for your vector<>, or are you looking for a generic solution (which at this point I'm somewhat confident doesn't exist) ? I.e. you want this on a vector<variant_t>, vector<BYTE>, etc. ?

Answer (score 4):

This should copy the contents of the vector to the underlying SAFEARRAY directly, assuming they are simple types or pointers.

```
vector<T> vecInput;

// Create a SAFEARRAY of size elements
CComSafeArray<T> sa(vecInput.size());

// Copy all the contents into the SAFEARRAY
memcpy(&sa.GetSafeArrayPtr()->pvData[0], &vecInput[0], sizeof(T) * vecInput.size());
```

If you're looking for a generalized solution, iterating over the vector also works:

```
vector<T> vecInput;

// Create a SAFEARRAY of size elements
CComSafeArray<T> sa(vecInput.size());

// Copy all the contents into the SAFEARRAY
for (size_t i = 0; i < vecInput.size(); ++i)
    sa.SetAt(i, vecInput[i]);
```

If you want to use STL algorithms, there's at least [one solution that provides STL compliant iterators on top of a SAFEARRAY](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1677/STL-Compliant-Class-for-SafeArrays) after which you can call `CComSafeArray::Attach` to assign the SAFEARRAY to the CComSafeArray.

Comment: On the first solution, I get a compile error at memcpy, "expression must have pointer to class type".